# Dynamic LIKE in WHERE clause in T-SQL with STUFF and FOR XML Path

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What I'm trying to do is search a text column for anything `LIKE` anything in a list of values.

The table with the text column is very large, so I can't join on `LIKE '%' + valuename + '%'` (the list of values temp table is not terribly large).

I thought I would try to do it this way, but I need to get the single quotes around the `%` in the dynamic `WHERE` clause. Maybe this is not possible.

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE #SearchValues (valuename VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #SearchValues
VALUES ('Red235'), ('Blue678'), ('2Purple'), ('63Cyan'),('99Black')

CREATE TABLE #TextTable (textfield VARCHAR(300))

INSERT INTO #TextTable
VALUES ('"Red235"'), ('blah and [99Black]'), ('something else'), ('n'),
       ('63Cyan'), ('other text'), ('nothing'), ('[2Purple]'), ('')

SELECT 
    -- this would be it except that it needs the single quotes around the %
    WhereClauseIWant = STUFF((SELECT ' OR valuename LIKE %' + valuename + '%'
                              FROM #SearchValues
                              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 19, '') 

SELECT *
FROM #TextTable
WHERE textfield LIKE STUFF((SELECT ' OR valuename LIKE ' + '%' + valuename + '%'
                            FROM #SearchValues
                            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 19, '')
```

Comment: Thank you.  That did it.  I forgot about doing it this way.  I was trying to put the single quotes directly into the statement.

Comment: Why can't you join or use an `EXISTS`, I don't understand

Comment: Actually, with this table it looks like I can join on EXISTS.  I had tried joining on LIKE before, and I think I also tried using EXISTS in that case, in a different scenario with a different large table and eventually had to give up because it was taking forever.  
Thank you for the QUOTENAME and .value info.  I was not familiar with those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you should just use an `EXISTS` predicate in a static query.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM #TextTable T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM #SearchValues s
    WHERE t.textfield LIKE '%' + s.valuename + '%'
);
```

If you are *really* set on using dynamic SQL, you obviously need `EXEC`, and you need to do this **safely**. You also had some typos.

Note the use of `QUOTENAME` to inject safely, and `.value` to prevent XML entitization.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT *
FROM #TextTable
WHERE 1=0
' + (
    SELECT '
OR textfield LIKE ' + QUOTENAME('%' + valuename + '%', '''')
    FROM #SearchValues
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)');

PRINT @sql;  -- for testing
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```